# How do I change unique row values into another set of unique row values in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, row, data-wrangling

I have a data frame with the experimental results coming from participants who took my test online. In the data file, each unique participant is identified by a randomly generated code given to them at the end of the experiment. Since it is cumbersome to identify each person by a random code that looks like gibberish, I would like to replace these codes by readable labels like Participant_1, Participant_2, etc.

So I think I need a piece of code that identifies each unique random code in the data file and replaces them with the participant labels one by one. But I could not figure it out and any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a piece of code that shows the output I have vs. the output I want. Note that each participant has answered different numbers of questions, so this cannot be used as an easy way out to parse them.

```
Participant_Identifiers <- c(rep("QHDKWEFHWKHFFH", 4), rep("WHWIHFJNWFKWF", 7), rep("HEIFFFBBKQLSD", 3))

Participant_Scores <- c(20, 30, 59, 20, 47, 84, 21, 90,54,78,90,97)

df <- data.frame("Participant_Identifiers" = c(rep("QHDKWEFHWKHFFH", 4), rep("WHWIHFJNWFKWF", 7), rep("HEIFFFBBKQLSD", 3)), 
                  "Participant_Scores" = c(20, 30, 59, 20, 47, 84, 21, 90,54,78,90,97, 35, 67))

df

df_I_want <- data.frame("Participant_Identifiers" = c(rep("Participant_1", 4), rep("Participant_2", 7), rep("Participant_3", 3)), 
                       "Participant_Scores" = c(20, 30, 59, 20, 47, 84, 21, 90,54,78,90,97, 35, 67))

df_I_want
```

Comment: Please share representative & minimal sample data (in an ambiguous format using e.g. `dput`). Also include your expected output for the sample data you give. It's a lot easier for us to understand what you're trying to do if you share some specific data and output than if you describe your data in prose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `match` with `unique`

```
df$new_col <- paste0("Participant_", match(df$Participant_Identifiers, 
                                     unique(df$Participant_Identifiers)))
```

Or since `Participant_Identifiers` is factor, you can convert them to integer

```
df$new_col <- paste0("Participant_", as.integer(df$Participant_Identifiers))
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak! I believe this code works in a similar way to the code in a previous answer. It is really useful, and thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question <3

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do:

```
# example 
ano <- replicate(5, paste(letters[sample(1:25, 12, replace = TRUE)], collapse = ""))
df <- data.frame(pat = sample(ano, 15, replace = TRUE), var = runif(15), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

# 1. create another data frame with the id you want 
patu <- unique(df$pat)
df_id <- data.frame(pat = patu, id = paste0("Participant_", seq_along(patu)))

# 2. merge with your df 
res <- merge(df, df_id)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much for your kindness and ingenuity!